# Update ASPX/ASCX assembly references when auto-incrementing assembly versions in TFS builds

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tfsbuild

I am building a SharePoint project and using TFS2010 for my builds.  I have used the TFS community build extensions to successfully implement assembly version incrementing which I am happy with.

However, as my assembly is going into the GAC I need to update my ASPX/ASCX files to reference the assembly with the correct version.

Is there a "proper" or easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup in ASPX/ASCX files can have tokenized references so it shouldn't be an issue.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
```

Where you have to careful is with web parts and workflows. In both cases the fully qualified name of the assembly that implements the web part or workflow is stored in the content database.

My suggestion is that you do not update the assembly version number unless you plan on running the new version and the old version side-by-side. In the case where you are making changes that will effect currently deployed assets, you should change the assembly file version instead. You'll still be able to distinguish between assemblies but you won't break assembly references.

See [Configuring Versioning of Assemblies in SharePoint Automated Build](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/09/22/configuring-versioning-of-assemblies-in-sharepoint-automated-build.aspx) for more discussion on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I forgot I answered this question here and just discovered the token replacement.  Initially I thought this was only for SharePoint 2010 projects, but it seems to work when using WSPBuilder for SharePoint 2007 projects also.